# ForkJoinTask understanding

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, fork-join

What happens after subtask.fork() returns a `ForkJoinTask<Int>` object? compute() method was invoked many times after that but from where and how?

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to learn the concept of fork/join framework. I saw the code below online. I know after reading Java API that `subtask.fork()` returns a object of `ForkJoinTask<V>`, which is a `ForkJoinTask<Int>` in this case. What I couldn't understand is what happens after that? The output indicate that the `compute()` method have been invoked many times after that but from where and how?

```
public class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRecursiveAction mra1 = new MyRecursiveAction(100);
        ForkJoinPool fjp1 = new ForkJoinPool();
        fjp1.invoke(mra1);
    }

    private long workLoad = 0;

    public MyRecursiveAction(long workLoad) {
        this.workLoad = workLoad;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {

        //if work is above threshold, break tasks up into smaller tasks
        if(this.workLoad > 16) {
            System.out.println("Splitting workLoad : " + this.workLoad);

            List<MyRecursiveAction> subtasks =
                new ArrayList<MyRecursiveAction>();

            subtasks.addAll(createSubtasks());

            for(RecursiveAction subtask : subtasks){
                subtask.fork();
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Doing workLoad myself: " + this.workLoad);
        }
    }

    private List<MyRecursiveAction> createSubtasks() {
        List<MyRecursiveAction> subtasks =
            new ArrayList<MyRecursiveAction>();

        MyRecursiveAction subtask1 = new MyRecursiveAction(this.workLoad / 2);
        MyRecursiveAction subtask2 = new MyRecursiveAction(this.workLoad / 2);

        subtasks.add(subtask1);
        subtasks.add(subtask2);

        return subtasks;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Splitting workLoad : 100
Splitting workLoad : 50
Splitting workLoad : 50
Splitting workLoad : 25
Doing workLoad myself: 12
Doing workLoad myself: 12
Splitting workLoad : 25
Doing workLoad myself: 12
Doing workLoad myself: 12
Splitting workLoad : 25
Doing workLoad myself: 12
Splitting workLoad : 25
Doing workLoad myself: 12
Doing workLoad myself: 12
Doing workLoad myself: 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call invokeAll in order to split you work in two pieces instead of doing it manually, then 2 new threads would be created to 'compute' your result, and then if it's not small enough 2 new threads and so on..,

You can't predict in what order thread would be executed so the messages order would vary every time you run this code.

```
public class MyRecursiveAction extends RecursiveAction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyRecursiveAction mra1 = new MyRecursiveAction(100);
        ForkJoinPool fjp1 = new ForkJoinPool();
        fjp1.invoke(mra1);
    }

    private long workLoad = 0;

    public MyRecursiveAction(long workLoad) {
        this.workLoad = workLoad;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {

        //if work is above threshold, break tasks up into smaller tasks
        if(this.workLoad > 16) {
            System.out.println("Splitting workLoad : " + this.workLoad);

            invokeAll(new MyRecursiveAction(this.workLoad / 2), new MyRecursiveAction(this.workLoad / 2));

        } else {
            System.out.println("Doing workLoad myself: " + this.workLoad);
        }
    }

}
```

[Java doc of ForkJoinTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out. Really appreciate it. However, I have one more question I wish you could help me answer. After invokeAll(new MyRecursiveAction(this.workload / 2), new MyRecursiveAction(this.workload / 2)), each new MyRecursiveAction object created will straight away invoke the MyRecursiveAction.compute() method again? Is this correct?

Comment: Not straight away, it will depend when their thread is active but compute will be called yes.